# Given a large tree structure, is there an efficient algorithm to do querying or filtering on the tree?

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, graph-algorithm

Let's say I wanted all nodes whose parent(s) matched some certain condition.

Is there an accepted way of doing this other than inspecting each node and building a results object full of either nodes or subtrees?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the tree is not in already sorted or indexed based on the search condition in some way, then you cannot prune the tree traversal (i.e. you cannot decide to not take the right child at some particular node, for instance).  Therefore, you have no choice but to traverse the entire tree.

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty much it. You simply have to access each node to see whether it matches the criteria.

But there are some ways to speed it up:

- Use an index. If you are repeatedly querying the same property, it might be beneficial to create an index on that property and use for searching. This could speed up your code immensely. Doing is not free though: you need to calculate the index up front, update it every time you update the tree and you need more memory to keep it.
- If you have a multi-core machine, you can process individual subtrees in parallel by using separate threads.